# Override dependency of nuget package in post build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, dependency-management

I have a project A with dependency B via nuget. Dependency B comes from another team and is beyond my direct control.

The nuget package for B contains dependencies for B including Common.Logging v1.2. This is copied into place via the nuget targets file of B (something like `<Copy SourceFiles='@(PackageBManagedFiles)' DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\"/>`)

As it happens, I also require a reference to Common.Logging in project A, but with later version 3.0.  I have added this using nuget and the reference in Visual Studio *looks* ok.

As I need two versions of Common.Logging, I have added an `assemblyBinding` into the app.config file, something like:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="xxx" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

So ideally I'd like version 3.0 of Common.Logging to be in my bin directory.

However, version 1.2 ends up in my bin directory - and hence the application does not work.

I have tried to override back to version 3.0 using a post build event.  Echo-ing the contents of the bin directory to a file during the post build event (something like `dir $(TargetDir) > dir.txt`) show that the file copy has worked, but by the time the build has completed the old version of the file is back in place.

This suggests that the order of the build is as follows:

1. dependencies copied into place
2. post build events run
3. nuget targets file run for package B

This suggests that I could create my own nuget package with Common.Logging 3.0 containing a targets file to copy the new 3.0 dll over the top of the old 1.2 dll file - but only if I could guarantee the order that the nuget package / targets files were run in.

Any ideas how I can get Common.Logging 3.0 into my bin directory after a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" this by creating a new nuget package that contained Common.Logging 3.0, copied into place via the targets file, and naming the nuget package `zzzCommonLoggingToBeInstalledLast`.

Noticing that nuget seems to work through `packages.config` alphabetically, this did the job reliably on the local/build server.

A bit of a hack, but adding it in as it was a useful quick solution in the end, and I could add a few comments to explain the hack within the nuget package for other developers to understand what this was for. If anyone has a better solution, I'll happily delete this answer.